# Vue Pinia access other function in getters with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pinia

example store

```
  getters: {
    setName: (state) => (string: string) => {
      state.user.username = string;
    },
    setUser: (state) => {
      setName('Tom'); // setName is undefined.
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to access the setName inside an arrow function?

Example only show you can get `this` inside normal functions
https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/getters.html#accessing-other-getters

Comment: Why would a _getter_ mutate state?

Comment: how about for an action as an arrow function to access state?

Comment: The reason arrow functions are not supported in actions is a Typescript limitation https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/1240

Answer (score 6):

First of all, as Phil pointed out, `getters` feature should not mutate the state. As mutations are not included in Pinia, `actions` is the way to go.

Also, Arrow functions are meant to not have a `this` object reference. So, If you want to access any of the other store methods or variables in the state you should create an action with a regular javascript function syntax, like

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
export const useUserStore = defineStore('user', {
  state: (): myState => ({
    user: {name: 'myname'},
  }),
  getters: {
    getName: (state: myState) => state.user.name,
  },
  actions: {
    setName(newName: string) {
      this.user.name = newName
    },
  },
})
```

Then in any external file where you already imported the defined store, call the action just like this

```
import { useUserStore} from '~/stores/user'
const store = useUserStore()
store.setName('Tom')
```

Note: In Pinia actions you may want to always use regular javascript function syntax as those are in charge of changing data in your state.

Comment: Thanks for this clear example.
If I can ask... where do you define "myState" ?